# Custom pipe not found error in microfrontend remote app

Tags: angular-pipe, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Have created a microfronted app using the **Module federation framework** .
Have exposed module of the remote microfrontend to the shell app .
Have created a custom pipe in the remote module ,Have declared and export it as well from the remote app .
Whenever I call the component of the  microfrontend app directly the pipe works perfectly fine ,but when I call the same component from the shell app , then it is giving pipe not found error

Code of the custom pipe in remote app

```
@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent = 1): number {
    return Math.pow(value, exponent);
  }
}
```

Remote app exposed module code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    ExponentialStrengthPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,

    FeldNpRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [ExponentialStrengthPipe],

})
export class FeldNpModule {

}
```

Error when remote module component is called from shell app

```
 NG0302: The pipe 'exponentialStrength' could not be found in the 'DashboardComponent' component!.
```

Can someone please help why exactly am i not able to call the pipe of the remote app from the shell app .